# Bspline Basis Function In C

Tags: c, algorithm, bezier, curve, spline

I am trying to calculate Bspline Curves with the given Control Points. I've researched about Bplsines and the Bspline I am trying to draw is Uniform Quadratic Bspline. But I am not sure if i get it correct. Please help me with my confusion. If I am right the degree of the every single bspline curve is under my decision. So I want them to be quadratic. And the number of knots depends on the number of control points.
(number of knots = number of control points - 2).Because every single control polygon will be including three control points. The function I am calculating the knot vector is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfPoints-2; i++)
{
    if(1<=i && i <= k)
        knotArray[i] = 0;
    else if(k + 1 <= i && i <= n + 1)
        knotArray[i] = i-k;
    else if(n + 2 <= i && i <= n + k + 1)
        knotArray[i] = n - k + 2;

}
```

I don't know if this is correct. According the documention I read, the formula for calculating the knot vector is something like this.

And the method  I am using for calculating the basis function is:

t: funciton parameter

i: the basis function I am calculating

k: (degree of the curve) + 1. (in this case it is 3 at the beginning)

x[]: knot vector

```
float N(float t, float i, float k, float x[])
{
    if(k == 1)  //k = n + 1 (n is the degree of the curve)
    {
        if(x[i] <= t && t <= x[i+1])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}


     return (t - x[i] / x[i+k-1] - x[i]) * N(t, i, k-1, x) + (x[i+k] - t / x[i+k] - x[i+1])* N(t,  i+1, k-1, x);
}
```

[image: Basis Function Formula]

It doesn't even compile the code and I am looking for the bug atleast 3 hours.

If someone patient can teach me the basics of the Bspline Curve, i will be very thankful.

Comment: `x[i]` Why do you want to use a `float` as array index? Same for `k`, why not an `int`? If your code does not compile, you should at lease show the error messages. And provide a complete example, not only a few unrelated snippets.

Comment: You know basic math rules, do you? They are also valid in C. This `(t - x[i] / x[i+k-1] - x[i])` is not what is shown in your formula. It is same as `t - (x[i] / x[i+k-1]) - x[i]` while you need `(t - x[i]) / (x[i+k-1] - x[i])`. Add brackets to enforce precedence.

Comment: You might add a link to the document that you used as reference.

Comment: Please keep in mind that when `x[i+k-1] == x[i]` or `x[i+k] == x[i+1]`, the denominator in your expression will be zero. So do not return the expression itself. First, calculate the result of expression and check whether the denominator is zero. After you can return the result safely.

Comment: Yeah this code not seem match [what they should be implementing](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#bsplines).